# How to use -DApp -Dtime as name bound args to main method in java

Tags: java

How do i pass arguments to a  main program in Java 
So that the order of parameters is not bound to the `args[]` array index.

And No matter in what order the user enter the args i can map the right values to right field
in the function.

Hope this clarifies the query !

Thank
VR

Answer (score 0):

Specify them before your main class name and those would be available as System properties

```
for(String arg: args){
   System.out.println(arg);
}

System.out.println(System.getProperty("key1"));
```

with

```
java -Dkey1=val1 com.abcd.Main arg0 arg1
```

and

```
java -com.abcd.Main arg0 arg1 Dkey1=val1
```

you will get to know

Comment: getting more confused

Comment: what is the confusion ?

Comment: I want the order of arg to not matter what are the Dkey1=val1 means for args0 etc

Comment: wait you want to pass system argument or argument to main ?